# Open firefox new tab in same window through terminal

Tags: linux, firefox

I am using linux mint with mate desktop and I want to open a new tab using the terminal (sending the command through xbindkeys to be more correct) to the existing firefox session/window. `-new-tab` won't do it. The reason I want to do this is linked with this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148768/shortcut-to-google-selected-text

The reason for all this is to avoid memory bleeding and multiple windows generation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use existing instance of firefox you have to use `-remote` option:

```
firefox -remote "openURL(http://www.youtube.com, new-tab)"
```

Comment: This doesn't work on newer versions of Firefox. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1123804/48105 for an updated answer (`firefox --new-tab --url about:newtab`).